# Command line format description language

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface

Many man pages and `--help` option use a format for describing the command line options of the documented utilities. For instance, for the `cd` shell command:

```
cd [-L | -P] [directory]
cd -
```

I'd like to parse these descriptions. Is there a model or formal format (even if it is not widely accepted)?

I've seen that at least python's `argparse` (http://pymotw.com/2/argparse/) can generate something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Some details about the notation used for the SYNOPSIS section can be found in the [man manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html#SYNOPSIS):

> The following conventions apply to the SYNOPSIS section and can be used as a guide in
>   other sections.
>
> ```
>  bold text          type exactly as shown.
>  italic text        replace with appropriate argument.
>  [-abc]             any or all arguments within [ ] are optional.
>  -a|-b              options delimited by | cannot be used together.
>
>  argument ...       argument is repeatable.
>  [expression] ...   entire expression within [ ] is repeatable.
> ```
>
> Exact rendering may vary depending on the output device.  For instance, man will
>   usually not be able to render italics when running in a terminal, and will typically
>   use underlined or coloured text instead.
>
> The command or function illustration is a pattern that should match all possible
>   invocations.  In some cases it is advisable to illustrate several exclusive
>   invocations as is shown in the SYNOPSIS section of this manual page.

There are further details in the the [POSIX Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html).

Many libraries to parse the command line options can generate the synopsis section (e.g. take a look at [boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/program_options.html)).